# Which tense is it? Is it grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, tense

In the song *Honey You* by The Dead South there is a line that goes like this:

> "Then I looked into your eyes never understanding why
>   You would never run with me"

Is that a correct way to say? If so, can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: Song lyrics sometimes use non-standard grammar. But I don't see anything odd about this quote. Please explain what you think might be wrong about it.

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing wrong about your sentence. The tense of the first part of your sentence:

> Then I **looked** into your eyes...

is "simple past" and the tense of the second part is "future in the past":

> why you **would** never **run** with me...

which is used to express the way you thought something would happen in the future.

So the tense of your whole sentence is past. (simple past + future in the past)

Comment: I meant "never understanding why" part. Is it a continuous or a gerund? I didn't quite get it.

Comment: @AlexExlot No, I think it is not gerund. It's present participle. (*Participles* have no tense, we understand  the time referred to from the context)

Answer (score 1):

> Then I looked into your eyes never understanding why you would never
>   run with me.

The structure: Past Indefinite (looked) + adverbial participle with negation (never understanding) + Subjunctive Mood (would never run).

Probably, '**never understanding**' is the unclear part for you here. In other words, it's '**without any understanding**' or '**while absolutely not understanding**'.

Comment: Thanks! So "never understanding" is used as an adverb here?

Comment: It functions like an _adverbial participle_ here: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/adverbial_participle while technically it's just a participle.